# How can I deserialize a nested representation in Django REST Framework?

Tags: json, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model, (A), which I'd like to serialize in one form, and deserialize from another.

For instance, suppose my model (A) has fields which refer to other models, through either a vanilla one-to-many or a more complex many-to-many relation:

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    c = models.ManyToManyField(C, through=D)

    my_val = models.IntegerField()
```

I have a `ModelSerializer` subclass which used nested serializers to represent A.b and A.c. It looks something like:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    b = MyCustomBSerializer()
    c = MyCustomCSerializer(source=c_set, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = A
```

This works fine, and is able to give me a nice hierarchical representation for the requested instance of `A()`. `MyCustomBSerializer` and `MyCustomCSerializer` are invoked as expected, to give nice nested representations of the `b` and `c` relations.

NOW, this works fine for the `GET` method to my view. What I would like to do, for POST, PUT and other *write* methods, is be able to pass the foreign key IDs for the `b` and `c` fields, something like this:

```
{"b": 12,
 "c": [1, 4, 99],
 "my_val": 200}
```

How can I do this? Every reference I find to ForeignKey-based deserialization involves using  `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` as the serializer field type for both `b` and `c`. This isn't ideal, however, because it only serves up the primary key when serializing, e.g. `{"b": 12}` rather than `{"b": {"id": 12, "title": "My B title", "author": {"firstname": "Cynthia", "lastname": Dringus"}}, [...]}`

So my question is: Is it possible to serialize related fields in one format, and deserialize them in another?

Comment: you can refer the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own views you can specify different serializers for different methods.

A very basic example:

```
class SnippetDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a snippet instance.
    """

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = SnippetSerializerTypeA(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = SnippetSerializerTypeB(snippet, data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Note that we're using a different type of serializer in each method.